# why does my LinkListCreate function stop running?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, typedef, singly-linked-list

I want to creat a link list by `CreateLinkList(LinkList *L, int n)`, but the output of printf is `0 1` only.

It seems to stop at line 3 in `CreateLinkList`.

How can I fix it?

```
void CreateLinkList(LinkList *L, int n)
{
    srand(time(0));
    printf("1\n");
    *L = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); \\ it seems to stop here
    printf("2\n");
    Node *flag = *L; 
    printf("3\n");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        Node *newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->data = rand() %100+1;

        flag->next = newNode; 
        flag = newNode;
    }
    printf("4\n");
    flag->next = NULL;
    printf("5\n");
}

int main()
{
    LinkList *p;
    printf("0");
    CreateLinkList(p, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

The `LinkList` and `Node` were defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef Node *LinkList;
```

Comment: I ***guess*** you're trying to emulate pass-by-reference by passing a pointer to `LinkList`. Then you need to define `p` as a *non* pointer variable, and use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters this structure definition

```
typedef struct
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

is invalid. Within the structure the type `struct Node *` is not the same as the typedef name `Node`.

Write instead

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

Neither the node L nor the node flag are initialized.

```
*L = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)); \\ it seems to stop here
printf("2\n");
Node *flag = *L;
```

So this statement

```
flag->next = newNode;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover the pointer p is not also initialized in main

```
LinkList *p;
```

So even this call

```
*L = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

also invokes undefined behavior.

In any case it is a bad idea to use such a typedef like

```
typedef Node *LinkList;
```

because it only confuses readers of the code.

The function can be defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef Node *LinkList; 

void CreateLinkList( LinkList *head, unsigned int n )
{
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *head = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

        ( *head )->data = rand()  % MAX_VALUE + 1;
        ( *head )->next = NULL;

        head = &( *head )->next;
    }
}

void print( LinkList head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->data );
    }

    puts( "NULL" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    LinkList head = NULL;

    CreateLinkList( &head, 10 );

    print( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
14 -> 40 -> 17 -> 54 -> 8 -> 48 -> 40 -> 25 -> 99 -> 41 -> NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just started to learn C programing. I learned this strange coding style from a textbook and now I decided to quit this book...

Comment: @user10927531 Even a bad book is useful because it arises questions.:)

Comment: U are right. It is an easy-to-understand book but lacks depth. I'll go through it soon. Thanks.